# Transaction code created. Can't run it from command t/a line but can by Transaction->Execute. Why?

Tags: abap, sap-gui

Why can't I run the program typing the transaction code created for the program here:
[image]

but I can using Chosen Transaction->Execute->Direct Processing?
[image]

Comment: What's the name of your transaction?

Comment: Transaction name: ZOOO_MAINPRGM

Comment: And what message do you get when you try to run it in the tx code thing?

Comment: Function code ZOOO is not supported.

Comment: Please update your question: Add a complete (!) screenshot, not some crippled attempt to hide everything that is vital to answer your question. Describe exactly what you did, every single step.

Comment: You get `Function code ZOOO is not supported` but your Transaction name is `ZOOO_MAINPRGM`. Are you sure you used the complete name (including the underscore and the part beside it. Or did you mix up report name and transaction name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type in `/nZOOO_MAINPRGM` if you would like to run the transaction in the existing session, or `/oZOOO_MAINPRGM` if you would like to open a new session.

Given that you say you can execute the transaction from the workbench, this should work.  If it does, you should also be able to run your transaction using `ZOOO_MAINPRGM`, provided you are in the SAP main screen and not within another SAP transaction.